# xcodebuild fails to build SPM packages with catalyst support

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to build a mac catalyst project using the `xcodebuild` command line tool. The project was originally an iOS app that now supports mac catalyst. The project is using Cocoapods and Swift Package Manager as we have some libraries that don't support the latter. I'm using the following xcodebuild command

```
xcodebuild -workspace 'PROJECT.xcworkspace' -scheme 'MY_SCHEME' -configuration 'MY_CONFIG' CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='MY_IDENTITY' ENABLE_BITCODE=YES ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf-with-dsym
```

It fails with the following error

```
error: Signing for "RealmCore" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'RealmCore' from project 'RealmCore')
error: Signing for "Alamofire" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Alamofire' from project 'Alamofire')
error: Signing for "Realm" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Realm' from project 'Realm')
```

All the mentioned libraries were added using SPM. I don't understand why this fails. Do swift packages require a development team?

Also the problem only seems to be the addition of the mac catalyst target. I have a branch of the iOS app without catalyst support with the same SPM dependencies and `xcodebuild` works without problem.